# BroadcastReceiver onReceive not firing

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am currently trying to create a phone number verification on registering on my Android app. Thank you for your help to read my long post!

Here is my Manifest file with other activities omitted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.opensem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />


    <application
        android:name=".AppHelper"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        >
        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".OpenSem"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_opensem" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my class which I want to show a log on receive SMS

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Received");
    }
}
```

Here is my class sending the SMS

```
public class RegisterPageSubmitListener implements OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        number = ParamList.get("phone");
        code = randInt(100000, 999999) + "";
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, code, null, null);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I successfully send the SMS and received it on my phone, but the "Received" Log was never shown. I came across the priority problem on StackOverflow and thus I added the `android:priority="2147483647"` in my manifest. I then added these lines (Copied from another SO post) in other activities to see if my receiver is properly registered.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
        Log.d("OpenSEM", "Receiver name:" + info.activityInfo.name + ";     priority=" + info.priority);
    }
```

and the resulting log is shown below:

```
08-01 15:27:10.417: D/OpenSEM(12880): Receiver name:com.android.mms.transaction.HighPrivilegedSmsReceiver;     priority=1000
08-01 15:27:10.417: D/OpenSEM(12880): Receiver name:com.example.opensem.SMSReceiver;     priority=999
08-01 15:27:10.417: D/OpenSEM(12880): Receiver name:com.android.mms.transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver;     priority=0
```

It seems that my receiver's priority was set to 999 instead of 2147483647. Also, I didn't install any SMS applications, so the other priority=1000 receiver seems to belong to the system messaging application.

Did I do anything wrong? I tested my code on a Red MI (MIUI) and Samsung note II. My SMSReceiver seems to be registered and not receiving the SMS which was successfully sent back to both phones. I would really appreciate any help!!

Potato. For the long post.

Comment: 999 is the highest practical priority you can set for a receiver, which is why it shows that value. Are you sure don't have another SMS app installed, like Hangouts or Go SMS Pro? Also, which Android versions are you testing?

Comment: Make sure your path class path is correct

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
@Mike M. Good point! I overlooked Hangouts as it was pre-installed on my phone and I didn't notice. I have now uninstalled it, but still no luck.

Comment: You might try uninstalling/reinstalling your app since you've removed Hangouts. Hangouts somehow is able to hijack and take control of the priority chain, so it may still have some funky effect leftover. Otherwise, your code and setup seem right. Oh, and reboot your device, too.

Comment: @bean_droid I am not sure which class path to use, is `com.example.opensem.SMSReceiver` correct? I tried it but it doesn't work so I left it just `.SMSReceiver`

Comment: As long as your Receiver class is in the main project source folder, (i.e., the same folder as your Activity) that should be ok.

Comment: @Mike M. I reinstalled and rebooted my phone. Seems that the MMS Receiver with 1000 priority is still there, and the onReceive is still not called :/

Comment: You do have your Receiver in its own file, yeah? Also, which Android version?

Comment: Yes the Receiver is a separate class in its own file. The android version is 4.2.2

Comment: Well, I'm kinda stumped. It's gotta be the HighPrivilegedSmsReceiver aborting the broadcast, but I can't find much info on it. You might start digging through Settings to see if there's anything pertinent in the vendor layer that can be disabled. Who's your wireless provider?

Comment: Very much thanks for your time Mike, I'm from Hong Kong and using a data provider called "3". I will check through my settings and see what I get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may be the restrict of your ROM, that is MIUI, I have encountered the problem that my `BroadcastReceiver` can't receive broadcast, but my app is OK on SamSung phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, without any luck, I had changed the registration into forcing the user input the verification code themselves as a backup plan. It's been long and the app was shut down. Thanks anyways!